# View and Servlets in website class-diagram?

Tags: class-design, models, uml, class-diagram

I'm about to develop this small website, its basically a simple web app to store informations about patients for a doctor.
The company i have got the assignment from demands an introducton with a class diagram, honstly, i have done this already but only for standalone apps, i'm very new in designing class diagrams for websites.
What i'm using is the Ivar Jacobson's iterative metho with usecases, where a usecase includes:
Actors, scenario (representing user-system interactions when all goes fine), and worse case scenatio (solutions when something goes wrong).
By applying this i came to a good conclusion, a well prepared class diagram.
My problem is that i'm doubting whether or not i should include jsp views and servlets(in my case action beans since i use Stripes) in the diagram, i mean, the bridge between the business-classes and the user are the jsp-views and the provided info are going to be processed by the servlets (or action beans), would you include them in the class diagram?
For a small project tis might be not that relevant but what if you have a project with 30 views and 20 servlets, the diagram would become messy and huge.
Do you have some tips about it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only reason you need the class diagram is to satisfy the client, best find out what they're looking for first.

If however they're not specific (and ignoring the cynical options) I'd suggest the following:

- Create a "Domain Model" diagram.  i.e. capture the concepts in the domain and their inter-relationships.  So Doctor, Patients and associated stuff.
- Don't create a "design" class diagram - i.e. no jsps, servlets, etc. If necessary create a simple architecture picture instead showing how the application is layered.

Rationale: a domain model is good for checking scope and verifying domain rules (relationships).  A "design" class diagram only obfuscates that.  A proliferation of jsps, controllers, etc. hides the underlying architecture pattern while distracting from the useful stuff in the domain model.

hth.